# GroovyShell binding with implicit root object

Tags: java, groovy, metaprogramming

The following summarises an attempt to run a snippet of Groovy from a Java application. Snippet `$ROOT$.empty` binds happily to `Collection.isEmpty()` of the bound variable.

```java
String snippet = "$ROOT$.empty == true";
Expression e = new GroovyShell().parse(snippet, new Binding());
e.getBinding().setVariable("$ROOT$", Collections.emptyList());
e.run();
```

The following allows the concise syntax I want by wrapping the snippet as `$ROOT$.with{snippet}`. It means such snippets can be expressed quite neatly against their (known) contextual root object. It is 10x slower during execution though (measured with JMH)

```java
String snippet = "empty == true"; // << this is much nicer to see
Expression e = new GroovyShell().parse("$ROOT$.with{" + snippet + "}", new Binding());
e.getBinding().setVariable("$ROOT$", Collections.emptyList());
e.run();
```

Is there a (metaprogramming?) way to achieve the same syntax but performant (especially given we know the type of `$ROOT$` when parsing!)

Comment: The heavy part here is parsing. Consider to cache parsed script. Bind&run should be quite fast.

Comment: Code is MRE only. Parsed expressions are cached in a `ThreadLocal<Map<String, Expression>>` and the 10x performance comment was observed for bind+run of pre-parsed basic expressions (e.g. `$ROOT$.name.toLowercase()` vs `$ROOT$.with { name.toLowercase()}`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use DelegatingScript as base class for GroovyShell parser.

All expression evaluations will be redirected to `delegate` object.

https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/DelegatingScript.html

I did code in groovy, but it is very close to java.

```js
@groovy.transform.CompileStatic
def test2(Class<DelegatingScript> c){
    println("start $c")
    def t = System.currentTimeMillis()
    for(int i=0; i<2000000; i++){
        DelegatingScript e = c.newInstance()
        e.setDelegate(Collections.emptyList())
        e.run()
    }
    println("  end $c ${(System.currentTimeMillis()-t)/1000} sec")
}

def snippet = 'empty == true'
def cc = new org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilerConfiguration();
cc.setScriptBaseClass(groovy.util.DelegatingScript.class.getName());
GroovyShell gs2 = new GroovyShell(this.getClass().getClassLoader(), cc);
Class<DelegatingScript> dc = ((DelegatingScript)gs2.parse(snippet)).getClass()

test2(dc) //==> 0.68 sec
```

Comment: Nice. Will be a few days before I can give this a try but it looks appropriate

Comment: it is still slower then `$ROOT$.empty == true`, but faster then `with closure` approach...